# GEN2 RFID Can the User Memory Bank be read-protected

Tags: rfid

I'm looking for confirmation that it is NOT possible to read-protect the EPC, TID and User Memory banks on GEN2 RFID tags( they can only be write-protected). Only the Reserved Memory Bank, where the Kill and Access passwords are stored, can be read-protected. I'm asking because I've encountered secured tags that give a Read Error on the User Memory bank?
Thanks in advance.[[image: GEN2_Tag_Example]